# How is "suggested" used for adademic writing?

Tags: grammar

I'm an ESL student, and trying to write an paper. I found it very confusing on the usage of suggest. I have asked a proofreader for help, and the proofreader changed the my sentences like the following. But I think I heard that the that clause after "suggest" can only use the infinitive of the verb (be) rather than "is" or "was".
So is this "...suggested ecotourism be nature-based..." is the correct way or the following are correct?

> But what is ecotourism? This is not an easy question to answer, as
>   there are various definitions. Weaver & Lawton (2007), for example,
>   suggested ecotourism is nature-based, focuses on learning or education
>   and benefits the environment and local economy. More recently, Buckley
>   (2013) argued ecotourism is also concerned with sustainability,
>   although most government agencies regard ecotourism as nature-based
>   tourism and do not mention sustainability. Fennell (2014) also
>   suggested local culture was a part of the ecotourism experience,
>   defining ecotourism as nature-based tourism that focuses on preserving
>   the environment, benefiting the local economy and educating
>   travellers.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To my ear, the sentences carry different meaning. Yours indicates advice given, while the "correction" seems to mean a current state of being. Of course, if you go with your version, it would require a change in the form of _all_ verbs following "suggested".

Comment: When engaging scholars in this fashion, it is common practice to use the present tense, i.e., Weaver and Lawton suggest...

Comment: Have you noticed that the sentence paraphrasing Weaver and Lawton uses _suggested... is_, while the sentence from Fennel uses _suggested... was_?

Comment: @KarlG, I believe MLA favors present but APA favors past.

Answer (score 2):

Like most common words, the verb *suggest* has multiple meanings, and thus multiple numbered definitions in dictionaries. The following is #1 per *[American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/suggest):*

> To offer for consideration or action; propose: *suggest things for children to do; suggested that we take a walk.*

The verb *take* in the latter example is an example of the sort of subjunctive that is identical in form with the infinitive (without *to);* and presumably that kind of usage underlies what you have mistaken for an invariable rule.

In the sample sentences that you put forward, however, the verb is being used in a different sense, one that is properly complemented by a clause (with or without *that),* as a verb of saying:

> to mention, introduce, or propose (an idea . . .) for consideration . . . ([Random House Kennerman Webster’s College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/suggest), #1).

*Suggest* in this sense is one of a whole spectrum of verbs of saying that scholars use to attribute claims to one another, which is so big a part of scholarly writing as to be well-nigh definitive of it. This spectrum ranges from *note,* which indicates complete agreement with the claim in question, to *claim, pretend,* or *allege,* any of which cues a reader to be skeptical of the claim, and paves the way (via an adversative like *but* or *however)* for the writer to proceed to refute it. *Suggest* occupies an intermediate or non-committal position on this spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out there are two kinds of sense for the usage of "suggest". I'm curious if I encounter similar words in the future, how do I know its usage? I had googled suggest usage, but some of the top ranked sites, like [this](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/using-suggest/) and [this](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/how-to-use-the-english-verb-suggest/), did not mention the second usage sense. So that's why I was confused.

Comment: One of the better ways to acquaint yourself with the range of meanings for a given English word is to consult the dictionary aggregator site to which I link (twice) in my answer. Even that does not squarely identify the scholarly usage, though, by which *to suggest* is to advance a theoretical hypothesis rather than a practical decision or course of action. (The sites you link seem to focus on the practical sense exclusively.)